# How to Copy Text of a Filename Using nnn File Manager

Tags: debian, file-manager, nnn

Using [nnn](https://github.com/jarun/nnn) (which is a terminal-based file manager), how can you copy the text of a file or folder's name to the clipboard?

For your convenience, this will install and launch nnn in Debian (if you'd like to help me figure it out):

```
sudo apt install nnn ; nnn
```

Comment: One way, that I just discovered, is to press the `f` key. This displays the path, where I can then copy using my mouse. Is there a quicker way than this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be to use the [nnn plugin](https://github.com/jarun/nnn/blob/a335f94d05bc1270aec3f4bffcc092dae125f14f/plugins/README.md#running-commands-as-plugin-) functionality and pipe the name to `xclip`, for example:

```
export NNN_PLUG='s:! echo $nnn|xclip*'
```

and then hit `;s` to pipe the currently selected name to xclip

**Note:** Debian stable has a rather old version of `nnn` with which this solution won't work. I suggest to build `nnn` yourself or backport it from testing

Comment: In Debian 11, I added `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main` to the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Then, at a command prompt, I entered `sudo apt update ; sudo apt install nnn/bullseye-backports`. I received this error `E: Release 'bullseye-backports' for 'nnn' was not found`.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there is no package in bullseye-backports for nnn. You have to backport it yourself or just build it yourself or use the packages provided at https://github.com/jarun/nnn/releases

Comment: If you want user-confirmation afterwards, omit the final `*` in the above command.

Comment: notice this copies only the filename, not the full path

Answer (score 2):

To copy the full path, not just the name, in Wayland, use:

```
NNN_PLUG=s:-!echo $PWD/$nnn|wl-copy*
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a nnn plugin that allows you to copy absolute and relative paths [here](https://github.com/raffaem/cppath).